# convert first.obj to first.exe

Tags: matlab

please I would like you to answer me about that error when I compiled my C program(VC++ 2008) Thank you very, I would appreciate any help ..
Note :my program is to perform cosimulation between OPNET modeler 14.5 and MATLAB by using external cosimulation controller C program ....

this is output error in VC++ 2008 command prompt

`first.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.30729.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:first.exe
first.obj
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Interface_Value_Set 
    $referenced in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Interface_Value
    $_Get referenced in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Execute_Until r
    $eferenced in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Interface_Callb
    $ack_Register referenced in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Interface_Group
    $_Get referenced in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Load referenced
    $ in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Init referenced
    $ in function _main
    $first.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_Esa_Main referenced
    $ in function _main
    $first.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd better use command-line tools(such as makesim) provided by OPNET rather than Visual Studio. Since your cosim depends on OPNET headers and libraries, it is better to compile and link with OPNET toolchain.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply ..it's Ok. but also I used command-line tools for OPNET but I got the same errors That I displayed in my question (cosim_external_code2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__Esa_Interface_Value_Set referenced in function _main) so please reply me urgently thanks in advance ..

Comment: It's been a while since I last tried cosim.You may try run the 'op_mksim' toolchain in an OPNET shell rather than a default shell provisioned by the OS. The difference only lies in the environment variables. With OPNET shell you have all necessary EV set while you don't have them in a default OS shell.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply but please if you don't mind give me your email to talk with you in details because I tried change EV but still I got same errors I think I have problem in My code...thanks in advance...

Comment: so did you find anysolution?